# cassandra nodetool JPLISAgent.c error

Tags: java, cassandra, nodetool

i just installed cassandra 3.11 on a VM with Ubuntu 16.04 like it's described in the manual (https://cassandra.apache.org/download/). Before installing cassandra i installed the latest verion of openjdk. Now i'm at the point

> "Verify that Cassandra is running by invoking nodetool status from the
>   command line."

but this only gives a rather long error massage:

```
java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 884
error: null
```

-- StackTrace --

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1848)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:804)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:199)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:167)
```

So i'm not familiar with the programing behind nodetool and cassandra, can anyone help resolving this issue? Thanks in advance,
Herman

It seems to be a openjdk-9 Problem, because if i use oracle8 jdk it gives the well known "Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'" respond.